# Trouble creating custom sanitization function for user list dropdown

Tags: theme-customizer, select, sanitization

I'm trying to create a custom author info box on homepage which will automaically generate by getting the info from user profile when a user is selected from theme customizer.

I followed the code for user list dropdown in this [article](http://www.paulund.co.uk/custom-wordpress-controls) and it worked perfectly for me. but I don't know how to sanitize it.

Github Link for [Custom_User_Dropdown_control](https://github.com/paulund/wordpress-theme-customizer-custom-controls/blob/master/select/user-dropdown-custom-control.php)

The following is the example of code I used.

```
/* custom user dropdown control */
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_user_id', array(
    'default'           => '',
    'sanitize_callback'     => 'custom_sanitize_user_id',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( new Custom_User_Dropdown_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_user_id', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Select Author', 'text domain' ),
    'section'           => 'custom_author_info',
    'settings'          => 'custom_user_id',
)));
```

I Just want to sanitize the custom user list dropdown control.

I know how to sanitize a normal select list, but for this I have no Idea how to do it. The following is the example of code which I use for sanitizing normal select list.

```
function example_sanitize_code( $input ) {
    $valid = array(
        'option1' => 'option1',
        'option2' => 'option2',
        'option3' => 'option3',
    );

    if ( array_key_exists( $input, $valid ) ) {
       return $input;
    } else {
       return '';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help? :)

Comment: Support for third party plugins is [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  But, you can also use [esc_attr](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) or any of the other escaping functions (for data coming out of the db) or sanitization functions (for data going in) baked into WordPress core so you don't have to go roll your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *validate* the data then you'll have to try retrieve user via ID.

To only *sanitize* ID since it's numeric is enough to cast it as integer, `absint()` will work fine as a callback.